# Coding a posterior distribution in R

Tags: r, bayesian

This may be a ridiculous question but I'm very new to R (started 3 weeks ago) but I'm running a Gibbs Sampler and I'm drawing from a non-conjugate distribution. It's set up as               Yi|mu ~ N(1,4^2), mu~N(0,1) and sig^2~IG(2,1). I have the sampling part coded but I'm having trouble coding the posterior distribution to create the data to sample from. What I have so far is:

```
dev.new() #####Posterior predictive density ( ppd[1:lx] )for data on the grid x (new line)
#
lx = 200 (new line)
x = seq( min(yy) - .1*(max(yy) - min(yy)), 
     max(yy) + .1*(max(yy) - min(yy)), len = lx )

dev.new()
hist( yy, prob=T )

ppd = rep( 0, lx )

for( ii in 1:lx )
{
    ##### enter the code here, 
    ### ppd[ ii ] = mean( dnorm( .....
 }

 lines( x, ppd, col=2, lwd=2 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the Gibbs Sampler is but just searching [google](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ndjw1/teaching/sim/gibbs/gibbs.html):
It seems that the code for the distribution might be that:

```
gibbs<-function (n, rho) 
{
        mat <- matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = n)
        x <- 0
        y <- 0
        mat[1, ] <- c(x, y)
        for (i in 2:n) {
                x <- rnorm(1, rho * y, sqrt(1 - rho^2))
                y <- rnorm(1, rho * x, sqrt(1 - rho^2))
                mat[i, ] <- c(x, y)
        }
        mat
}
```

I think that [here](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ndjw1/teaching/sim/gibbs/gibbs.r) from the same page will find the complete code you want R.
In this other [page](http://www.sci.csueastbay.edu/~esuess/psgs/120119PSGSAnsMast.pdf) you might find some more explanations and examples